# How to create a binary window for an event in Python

Tags: pandas, events, intervals

I have some sensor data and I know when the main event happens, but there's some noise before and after this event, and so I want to create a binary window where I can then just through away all the non important information.

Here is a toy example.

```
eg=pd.DataFrame({"Seconds":[0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5],
                "Event":[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
                "Start":[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
                "End":  [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                "Want": [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1]})
```

I have generated my start and end with shifting.  What I cannot seem to create in Python is my Want.  The  start and the end are more than 1 row away from the event, albeit they are fixed intervals.

In excel I am able to create a 3 nested that effectively does the following:

```
fup_bottom["Want"]=np.where(fup_bottom.End==1,0,
                           np.where(fup_bottom.Start==1,1,
                                   np.where(fup_bottom.Want.shift(1)==1,1,0)))
```

In python this doesn't work because the "Want" doesn't exist yet.

I have tried recording the seconds where Start is 1 and forward filling, and then similarly where End is one and backward filling.  However, this leads to Want always being 1 after the first event.

I greatly appreciate any help on this.  I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours and am stuck.
J

Comment: Is event always one row at a time? if yes then you want a 3-row window centered on each event row, right?

Comment: Not necessarily but its ok to be a little rough around the edges. I'm dealing with millseconds and the event is up to 6 milliseconds long... if you can provide me with something to run assuming 1 period then that would be a great start.

Comment: still not sure to fully understand, but try this `eg['Want'] = (eg['Event']|eg['Event'].shift(1, fill_value=0)|eg['Event'].shift(-1, fill_value=0))` it gives the expected output in this case :)

Comment: So the start will actually be 60 rows before the event and the end will be 80 rows after the event.  In order to use your approach I need to do this 140 times or create a for loop which (I assume) will be hugely inefficient.

Comment: indeed not the best appraoch then. try this `(eg['Start'] - eg['End'].shift(1, fill_value=0)).cumsum()`

Comment: I think thats worked!!